# bower.json manually adding dependency of installed package

Tags: frontend, bower

I installed package with bower.

This package has dependency of another package, but bower doesn't know it.

How do I manually add installed package dependency to be something in bower.json file?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way of doing this so here are a number of solutions:

- fork the project on on `github` for example, add the correct `dependencies` in `bower.json` and use that repo in your own project (optionally you can then issue a `pull request` to the origin author)
- use the unofficial [`overrides`](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files/blob/98f370f8791087345613eaeb301cea3b7d876dbb/README.md#overrides-options) property to override the package `dependencies` as need, and then use a build tool such as [`main-bower-files`](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files), [`wiredep`](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep)
- use a custom [`pluggable resolver`](http://bower.io/docs/pluggable-resolvers/) (a bit of an overkill just for this)

Answer (score -1):

Install package again with command: bower install  --save

Comment: You misunderstood the question.